# Perl script to copy rows to place in new file

Tags: perl, grep

I have a lot of text files in  a folder. The folder is 'c:\vehicles'. For every text file, I want to copy any row that includes the words: model, make, year.    The file I want to write to is 'vehicles.txt' and located in 'c:\'.

I know I've written the code wrong. What should I do to correct it? Thanks for the help.

`C:\vehicles $ ls -A | xargs head -qn 30 | perl -Mstrict -wne  'if( $ +_ =~ /(make)|(model)|(year)/ ) { print "$_"; }' > vehicles.txt
grep -rE "(make|model|year)" c:`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the following will help:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

for my $file (<*.txt>) {
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;

    while (<$fh>) {
        chomp;
        print "$_\n" if /(?:\b(?:model|make|year)\b)/i;
    }
    close $fh;
}
```

Assuming the script will be in `c:\vehicles`, type `perl scriptName.pl >vehicles.txt` at the command prompt.
The `<*.txt>` notation returns a list of all text files in the directory.  Each of these files are opened and read, line by line.  If any of the words your looking for are found on a line, it's printed.  The `>vehicles.txt` notation means to print to the file.

Comment: Do you see a file called `vehicles.txt` in the directory?

Comment: Matching the common leading `m` separately seems pointless and makes the code much less readable.