# Need to fix perl script for reading files and writing to new file

Tags: perl, parsing

I need to copy each row of a document that contains the words "make", "model", "year". I will need each row to be put into a new file. There will be other info in each of those rows. i.e.: make: ford, model:fusion, year: 2004.

I need to repeat for 300 files located in the same folder and all copied data will be written to the same file. The documents are long but the words are guaranteed to be in the top 30 rows.

My data is located in the directory 'c:\incoming\temp'. The file I want to write to is vehicles.txt.

I don't know if I should make a file or will the script make it for me? Any help will be appreciated, even if you have to write it out exactly for me. I don't know anything. I'm as desperate as one can be to get this thing to work. Once again, all the help is appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict; 
use warnings; 
my $dir_path="\Incoming\Temp"; 
opendir (Incoming\Temp, $tmp_dir) or die $!; 
open (MYFILE, '>>vehicles.txt'); 
while (my $file_name = readdir(Incoming\Temp)) {print "$file_name\n";} print MYFILE $file_content; close (MYFILE); CLOSEDIR;
```

Comment: You've asked about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514955/perl-script-to-copy-rows-to-place-in-new-file/) (without continuing a dialog) and at [PerlMonks](http://perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=1015083).

Comment: Re "I don't know if I should make a file or will the script make it for me?", computers don't do anything unless you tell them to.

Comment: Re "Any help will be appreciated", then perhaps you should have posted a question indicating what you needed help with?

Comment: Re "even if you have to write it out exactly for me", StackOverflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Opening a file in any reading mode (`>`, `>>`, `+<`) creates a new file if it doesn't already exist. This is [documented behaviour](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html). Also, the backslash is to be avoided. Inside strings, it introduces escape sequences; it also is the reference operator. Use forward slashes in paths. Restrict your variable names to characters in `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't ask a question. How about we get your code compiling?

The first arg of `opendir` is var to take a file handle (you'll later pass to `readdir`).

```
opendir(my $dh, $tmp_dir)
   or die("Can't open dir \"$tmp_dir\": $!\n");
```

You really should use a var for the first arg of `open` too.

```
open(my $fh, '>>', 'vehicles.txt')
   or die("Can't open \"vehicles.txt\": $!\n");
```